# How to install maxima in Heroku

Tags: heroku, maxima

Tryied to install the symbolic mathematics library: Maxima on Heroku server with Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. I followed the heroku-buildpack-apt https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt. It seems to be not well installed, when I call maxima from bash it just output `personality failure 13`. Need help to install Maxima with this method or an other one, my application runs well in the local machine.

Comment: My advice is to build Maxima from source, it's easy for Linux systems. Ubuntu releases of Maxima are typically out of date and I see that 18.04 has Maxima 5.41 is almost 3 years old. You can obtain the most recent tar.gz (5.44 at present) from Sourceforge and then it's just `./configure --enable-foolisp && make && make install` where foolisp is your Common Lisp implementation of choice; I recommend SBCL, you'll need to install that separately. Note wxMaxima needs to be installed separately if you want that. For tar.gz see: https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/files/Maxima-source

Comment: @RobertDodier I installed sbcl but when run it says: `sbcl: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.28 not found (required by sbcl)` when I run `ldd --version` it says `ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1.2) 2.27`

Comment: Hmm, I don't know what's going on there. My advice at this point is to compile SBCL as well.